# DocuSign "unable able to convert document" when i create create envelope with word file

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating a DocuSign envelope and I pass docx file for signing process. But I get the error code "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT". I am passing extension `docx` in document object.
This is my code

```
Dim doc1 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc1b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64
doc1.Name = "Sample"
doc1.FileExtension = "docx"
doc1.DocumentId = "1"
envelopeDefinition.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
doc1
}
```

For Pdf i passed like this

```
Dim doc1 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc1b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64
doc1.Name = "Samplepdf"
doc1.FileExtension = "pdf"
doc1.DocumentId = "1"
envelopeDefinition.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
doc1
}
```

Is any other place need to specify document extension? I am using sdk ver 5.9.0 for your reference. When using pdf file no problem.
But same word file pass through DocuSign UI (website) no problem.

Comment: Can you use same exact document directly from the DocuSign web app?

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the answer which best answers your question. Thank you!!***

Comment: @InbarGazit, yes i can send same docx file for sign using Docusign web app and get a mail for signing, no problem

Comment: @AravindAravind. Can you try this, just to eliminate the document itself as an issue.
DocumentBase64 = "VGhhbmtzIGZvciByZXZpZXdpbmcgdGhpcyEKCldlJ2xsIG1vdmUgZm9yd2FyZCBhcyBzb29uIGFzIHdlIGhlYXIgYmFjay4="

Comment: If this works - the issue is with getting the docx into base64.
If this doesn't work - then the issue is getting any document this way from VB.NET

Comment: Hi inbar, still i am getting error "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT"
this is what i pass for document object Dim doc1 As Document = New Document With {
.DocumentBase64="VGhhbmtzIGZvciByZXZpZXdpbmcgdGhpcyEKCldlJ2xsIG1vdmUgZm9yd2FyZCBhcyBzb29uIGFzIHdlIGhlYXIgYmFjay4=", .Name = "NDA Ace", .FileExtension = "docx", .DocumentId = "1" }

Comment: Not sure, its suddenly start to work when use docx files

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `.docx` as a part of the document's name:

```
doc1.Name = "Sample.docx"
```

Unfortunately, including just the `FileExtension` attribute is not enough.

Comment: Hi, i added name with extension for docl.Name, still getting same error , i am using SDK ver 5.9.0.This is the error message "Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT","message":"System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(Sample.docx) to a PDF. Error: UserId:xxxxe4bc-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cb1e87ebxxxx IPAddress:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Source:ApiRESTv2_1:Conversion failed. FileType: docx  Error: ActivePDF completed without success: [-1100] OpenInputFileFailed"}"

Comment: As Inbar says, since the document is working from the DocuSign web app, the problem is that you're either not reading the document in binary mode or you are not converting it to base64 correctly. Please **edit** your question to add in the code you are using to read to the document.

Comment: Hi, above i edit code for passing base64string format for Docx file , still word file getting same error, And same code used for pdf file no problem its working.

Comment: For passing base64string format, i first convert file to byte and then convert byte to base64string format.
 Dim doc1DocxBytes As String = Convert.ToBase64String(filebyte), same code used for pdf file its working

Comment: Not sure, its suddenly start to work when use docx files